# Is it possible to debug inside an anonymous method in startup?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to debug inside the options.Events.OnTokenValidated event in start up. But I can't debug line by line.

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
                
                options.Events.OnTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {

                    string userName = context.Principal.Identity.Name;

                    return Task.CompletedTask;


                };

            });
```

I am using .net 6.

Answer (score 1):

All MS services follow the [Options Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Those lambda's which configure option classes, are all turned into `IConfigureOptions<...>` services that are registered for you.

These `IConfigureOptions<...>` services will only be created and executed, in order to inject an `IOptions<>` service on first use. So if you put a breakpoint in one of these lambda's, you'll have to trigger the relevant service before it will execute.

If you are having trouble setting breakpoints on the correct line, you could turn the lambda into a local function or method on a class.